# c++ pass by reference safely and compile time checking on size

Tags: c++

```
SpiDeviceDriver::SPI_Error SpiDeviceDriver::SPI_ReadBytes(
   quint32          size_,
   QVector<quint8>& rxData_
)
{
     //Get data and fill QVector<quint8> with data
}
```

I'm trying to call a class function (from another class) and pass in a `QVector`, then fill it with data.

1. I prefer to just pass in the `QVector` alone (without the `quint32` size parameter) and then figure out the size from that and fill it with data according to its size. However, if the passed in `QVector` is size 0, I'd either have to assume it is meant to be size 1, creating a new spot for the data, or throw/handle the error at run-time, which i'd rather not do. Compile time error checking would be much better. Is there a better way to do this?
2. I guess you could pass in a `quint32 size_` parameter, then forget what the size of the `QVector` is and force the resizing to be that size. This seems awkward as well

**Note:** I've been instructed by my boss to make every function return an `enum` error code, so just using a `size_` and creating a vector, then returning that data is not an option.

Comment: Why do you actually need `size_` parameter at all? You can actually `resize()` that `rxData_` vector as often you need to, and _Get data_ as long it's available.

Comment: If you know the size at compile time (which is a prerequisite for checking it at compile time), you can use a template wrapper with an int template parameter. I suspect though that that isn't the case, and you are logically *bound* to check at run time. Btw, if size 0 is really an (exceptional) error you can throw an exception instead of returning an error code.

Comment: I'm also unsure what the function should accomplish (does it read the vector or does it fill it from somewhere?), and consequently unsure what the purpose of the `size_` parameter is.

Comment: yah it really isn't needed. It was just put in to demonstrate option 2. As to your second point, I need the calling class to define how many bytes need to be read. It's complicated but the short of it is the calling class needs to say read x bytes

Comment: @PeterSchneider I'd suspect reading in as many bytes as are actually available from a SPI device.

Comment: @ Peter Schneider Yah I don't know the size at compile time :( I was just hoping that there was some sort of compile-time check against knowing what it should not be (ie. 0)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  yah this is usually the case with SPI but we need the data to be optimized to be read quickly, and it isn't the usual SPI setup. It is using a SPI_READY line etc etc complicated setup. Basically we found that it is better to read the first byte (being the size of the SPI message) then all other bytes after will be read and then closed

Comment: @ Peter Schneider the function will call a system driver, which will pull data from a SPI line, and then fill the QVector with data, returning the QVector with data back to the calling function

Comment: @user2654735 Well, what about having two separate functions then? One to read the number of available subsequent bytes, and another one actually to consume them. A buffer for the latter one, could be easily setup knowing the number of bytes in advance?

Comment: _"I'm told every function should return an enum error code"_ Where did you hear that? The 1970s? :)

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Yah that's kind of what I was thinking, but you could really just reuse the same function aye? You could just call this function and read the first byte, then from that read the subsequent bytes.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit lol yah, I know right =P You didn't know that the boss is always right!? lol

Comment: This question does not deserve downvotes. I gave you an upvote to bring you back to zero.

Comment: @Krythic: It is not your job to "undo" other people's right to vote. It is also not your job to decide for everybody on what the post's final score should be. If you think that this question is useful and helpful then by all means +1 it, as you would any question, but please do not +1 just because somebody else saw fit to -1. That's not right. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What, are you playing mini-mod tonight? What makes you think that you have the right to tell me how I should spend my points? Not only are you being a total hypocrite right now, but you're coming off as extremely condescending. Stackoverflow doesn't need people who intentionally alienate others and behave in such a childish manner as this. This is a website for learning, not for petty bickering. If you need external validation, seek it elsewhere.

Comment: @Krythic: Once you've calmed down, read through [this mod post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74667/155739). Then stop committing voting fraud. Then continue to calm down. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to read from a data source into the given vector. Apparently the application knows at run time how many bytes are expected, hence the idea of a size "in" parameter. But that is redundant: QVector (cf. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#QVector-2) has a constructor which takes a size argument and a `size()` member function. Therefore, the expected number of bytes can be communicated by passing a vector of the proper size.

If that is deemed not explicit and obvious enough nothing except a certain redundancy speaks against a size parameter though. It would also bundle vector initialization code in the function.

Which leads to another alternative: To create and return a vector from the function (as value). Whether that is too costly depends on QVector's ability to be "moved" (doesn't look like it) or the compiler's return value optimization capabilities.

Error handling is another issue. The caller could check for short reads by inspecting the vector's size upon return. Shorter than required sizes indicate an error. If different reasons for error must be communicated there is a choice between exceptions or, indeed, error return values. The latter would imply to "return" the vector through some indirecting parameter.

**Update** regarding the special case of a request to read 0 bytes: This could also be handled as a legit (possibly diagnostic) request, as is done by the `read()` of the C standard library, cf. http://linux.die.net/man/2/read. If the line is ok, the return enum is "success" and the function does nothing and returns an empty vector. If an error condition is detected (no idea whether that's actually possible), the appropriate error is returned. Treating 0 byte read requests as NOPs fits nicely with many algorithms, the same way empty strings or vectors do.

Comment: I agree the best way of doing it is to initialize it within the function and return it. For whatever stupid reason, during my last design review, the reviewer said all functions need to return an enum error code. He said the only time functions should not return an enum error code is if there are no failure modes. Stupid, but it is what it is.

Comment: Also, agreed the size_ is pointless. It was just put in to demonstrate option 2. The constructor for QVector is what i'm using but unfortunately the problem with this is the default constructor creates a QVector of size 0

Comment: Not necessarily stupid -- perhaps a little old school. Not every system has exceptions. Error return values are plain and simple. Everybody understands them. Control flow is obvious (if tedious). Lots of advantages in real life. Many choices are questions of taste and consistency more than anything else. He does it that way, fine.

Comment: "the default constructor creates a QVector of size 0" -- well? :-) Use one of the many other ones!

Comment: erm yah I guess you are right :O Erm well after thinking it over, I guess I was kind of retarded in thinking that there would be a way to setup a compile-time checking. If the size is determined at run-time, there will be no way to compile-time check. I was just hoping that maybe there would be a way to invert the problem or something. Maybe you could pass a size and a pointer to the QVector or something and then just dynamically size it or something, I dunno. But that all seems verry akward

Comment: yah no I agree it shouldn't use size 0 :o the idea is to prevent anyone from using size 0 as a validation check

Comment: Alright it seems the best way to handle this is to throw/handle the size 0 error at run-time. Thanks for all the help! +1 for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

That coding standard to return an error code with every function/method really, really sucks for C++. If you can find a way to persuade otherwise diplomatically, I would suggest trying.

You can use thread-local storage to set and retrieve global errors efficiently on a per-thread basis that you can poll any time. You also have exception-handling in C++ and can translate exceptions into error codes at appropriate API/transaction boundaries. It would also still be better to accept a contextual parameter by reference with every function where you can set the error code through it than be forced into returning error codes for everything.

That said, I've been there and done that with shoddy legacy-style coding standards.

So if you have no other option, I would suggest `no` to your idea of making the function work on a pre-sized version of `rxData_` only.

If you are favoring that kind of `output parameter` type of design, strive to make it output-only when you can. It'll give your design a greater consistency. Don't get fancy with it. Pretend it is the return value. If you pretend that, `rxData_` doesn't provide the function with any input information and you'd need `size_` anyway.

Don't double up its responsibility as both input and output when you're using the reference like it's an emulated return value even though it's a parameter. That tends to lead to a confusing design and it'll make it difficult to make up your mind about it, so I'd suggest keeping both parameters and resizing the vector accordingly inside the function to match.

If it's an empty vector or one with a different size than intended, you would have had to resize it anyway outside, so you're not saving cycles. If it was the same size, then calling `resize` with the same size would generally be trivial as it would just skip the process.